# Poisson for 2 conditions in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Now in cell G2 the formula counts the Poisson distribution for two teams (highlighted in green and orange). **How can I make the Poisson** distribution in the formula count **for Barcelona in the rows where there is an "H" next to the score, and for Real Madrid in the rows where there is an "A"?**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13LTLg9MvBcwGyNr1kvSMw-OjG-0FMBvP8-rORSjNQAk/edit#gid=0

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( POISSON.DIST(G1,AVERAGE({B3:B,E3:E}),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=poisson(G1,average(ifna({filter(B3:B,A3:A="H");filter(E3:E,D3:D="A")})),1)
```